# Country field type get Null in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I created a FormType which add a country field type like this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('address', 'text', array(
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('country', 'country', array(
            'required' => false,
        ));
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => $this->dataClass,
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'form_contact';
}
```

I set **data_class** option for this form to an entity which have these 2 fields with **address** and **country** are both **string** type

Redering the form and submit it is OK, The POST params include

```
form_contact['address'] = 'Some value'
form_contact['country'] = 'US'
```

But when I persist the entity from the form submitted, country field is NULL. Dump **$form->getData()** I got this:

```
object(Namspace\Entity\MyEntity)#3501 (3) {
  ["id":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["address1":protected]=>
  string(12) "Some value"
  ["country":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["US"]=>
  string(2) "US"
}
```

I expect the country is US not new element with key and value US. Can you help me? Thanks alot

Comment: I found out it's my mistake. In my entity country setter. It should be $this->country = $country instead of $this->$country = $country that can lead to the problem. thank for your help nifr

Comment: If you think this could help someone in the future, please post an answer with your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to bind your entity to your form in your controller.

Therefore the submitted formdata ( though present ) is not being populated on your entity when `$form->bind($request)` is called.

```
public function submitAction(Request $request)
{

    $entity = new YourEntity();
    $form = $this->createForm(new YourFormType, $entity); // <- see here
    $form->bind($request);

    if ($form->isValid) {
       $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
       $em->persist($entity);
       $em->flush;
```

Comment: No luck, this problem still occur